# Can not push codes from local to sandbox org through sfdx vs code

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I have a sandbox org and i want to push source code in it which is available in my local directory.
I have successfully authorize the sandbox org with vs studio
Now i am trying to push the code with this command : sfdx force:source:push -u [usernameororg]
But it is throwing below error

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "INVALID_TYPE",
  "message": "\nMemberName, IsNameObsolete FROM SourceMember WHERE MemberName IN\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:52\nsObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are 
attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "SourcePushCommand",
  "stack": "INVALID_TYPE: \nMemberName, IsNameObsolete FROM SourceMember WHERE MemberName IN\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:52\nsObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.\n    at HttpApi.getError (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\jsforce\\lib\\http-api.js:250:13)\n    at C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\jsforce\\lib\\http-api.js:95:22\n    at tryCallOne (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\promise\\lib\\core.js:37:12)\n    at C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\promise\\lib\\core.js:123:15\n    at flush (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\asap\\raw.js:50:29)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at SourcePushCommand.catch (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\ToolbeltCommand.js:253:46)\n    at async SourcePushCommand._run (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:85:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\@oclif\\config\\lib\\config.js:173:24)\n    at async SfdxMain.run (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\main.js:27:9)\n    at async SfdxMain._run (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\command.js:43:20)\n    
at async Object.run (C:\\Users\\Linux\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.126.0-eb014a2\\dist\\cli.js:162:47)",
  "warnings": []
}
```

I couldn't figure out what this error is

Thanks,

Comment: Have you got the source code organised in an appropriate source folder structure?

Comment: Hey Phil, yes and in fact i am able to push the code to new scratch org and but getting the error while pushing it to sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure to [enable Source Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm) in Sandboxes.

Until the Source Tracking is enabled, you will need to use `sfdx force:source:deploy` or `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`

Comment: Got it thanks! i have enabled it through production and seems working now. Thanks